# Responsive menu links not working on mobile

Tags: html

```
<nav class="menu-panel" id="res-menu">
<div class="logo-holder">
<a href="#"><img src="assets/images/footer-logo.png" alt="">
</a>
</div>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>Home</a>
<ul class="collapse sub-list" id="list-1">
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
</li>
```

This is just partial, site is bonburger.ca works fine on desktop version but not on mobile

My mobile navigation does not work, but desktop navigation works fine

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using

Comment: bootstrap-transition.js v2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

for using collapse you need to us it on button

```
         <li>
 <button data-target="#list-1" data-toggle="collapse" 
  href="home.html" class="" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-down 
  pull-right"></i>Home</button>
 <ul class="sub-list collapse in" id="list-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
 <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
</li>
```

style according to it

Comment: thank you as i have been trying for awhile now, so i just had the info from li to li and change it according to the links i have on my site IE: about us, contact, menu etc.

Comment: something isnt right, now it has two sets of dropdowns, they dont seem responsive on my mobile site